# Webklex php-imap custom flags

Tags: imap, flags, php-7.4, php-imap

I struggle with the mentioned lib and use of custom flags. The IMAP protocol specs states that system flags starts with , keywords do not have any prefix.
There is the class Message with its methods setFlag and unsetFlag but it adds everytime the backslash as prefix:

```
$flag = "\\".trim(is_array($flag) ? implode(" \\", $flag) : $flag);
```

Is there any way around it or have I to implement this functionality by my own - or is there a general misunderstanding on my side?

As a side note: I have to use the API version 4.x

Comment: Found same issue (2021) - [github issue](https://github.com/Webklex/php-imap/issues/119) - If I see it correctly, this "\\" in setFlag is still present in the main version as well. If you would like to modify it, can submit a pull request. If you're interested, the reason why it is mandatory to use the backslash prefix for tag: [RFC 3501 standard for IMAPv4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-11)

Comment: It seems that this behavior is correct. Looking at common mail clients like thunderbird you will see that flags and keywords are seperated in the context menu for mails. My workaround is a method, which adds "flags" without backslash to mails which is sufficient for my current project. To get this working it must be mentioned that all keywords you want to add must be part of the config option 'flags' because otherwise you won't get them back with $message->getFlags()